# Ubuntu: How to find unallocated partition/free space?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, partition, fdisk

I've a legacy dedicated server with Ubuntu onboard (console mode only). Based on docs (prices etc.) I see that server must have 250+ GB, but I see significantly less:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1              3.7G  1.6G  2.2G  43% /
none                  2.0G  196K  2.0G   1% /dev
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
none                  2.0G  3.2M  2.0G   1% /tmp
none                  2.0G   84K  2.0G   1% /var/run
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /var/lock
none                  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr  4.0G  2.2G  1.9G  55% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-var  4.0G  1.9G  2.2G  48% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home
                      4.0G  1.8G  2.3G  45% /home
```

I've no idea who/when and how configure that server. Unfortunately, I can't reinstall it from the scratch.

So my question, **how can I find free partions/unallocated spaces**?

Just in case it's so easy:

```
$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4ed88842

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1         487     3911796   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2             488         731     1959930   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3             732       60801   482512275   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0b9943b0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1         487     3911796   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2             488         731     1959930   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3             732       60801   482512275   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md1: 4005 MB, 4005560320 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 977920 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md3: 494.1 GB, 494092484608 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 120628048 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md3 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two 500GB hard disks. They are configured to have the first partition (4 GB) mirrored as a RAID for `/` (`/dev/md1`), two 2 GB partitions (one on each disk) for swap and another RAID mirror taking up the remaining space (`/dev/md3`).

I assume that `/dev/md3` is configured as a physical volume for LVM, containing the volume group `vg00`, which in turn has three 4GB volumes (for `/home`, `/usr` and `/var`).

You can check the status of the LVM with `vgdisplay` and either extend existing volumes with `lvextend` or create new ones in the empty space with `lvcreate`.

For more infos, see the manual pages for the commands I listed.

Comment: In my case it was sequence of lvextend + xfs_growfs

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are running `lvm` on your disk. Run the `vgdisplay` command to see available space.

```
vgdisplay
```

To add more space to a logical volume, you can use `lvextend`.